Question regarding Gorenstein ring
I am trying to prove if R is a zero dimensional Gorenstein ring, and if $x$ is a nilpotent element, then $R/x$ is also Gorenstein.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: Okay, So since we are trying to prove Gorenstein ring; we have to localise it at each prime ideal and then we have to check if the socle is going to be a one dimensional vector space or not. So essentially I am unable to prove that socle of $R_m/xR_m$ is going to be a one dimensional since socle of $R_m$ is.

I don't think the statement is true. Take $R=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^3,y^3)$. Clearly, $R$ is a zero-dimensional Gorenstein ring with socle equals $(x^2y^2)$. Take $r=x^2+y^2$. It is easy to see that $r^3=0$. Now $R/(r)$ is isomorphic to $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^3,x^2+y^2,y^3)$. Note that the socle of $R/(r)$ contains $xy$ and $x^2$. So $R/(r)$ cannot be a Gorenstein ring.

Thank you so much!
